# Detect all accents not found in English or French

Tags: javascript

I find myself needing to detect whether a string contains any characters that do not exist in English or French. The string is gathered via HTML input field.

I have found a few examples of how to normalize the string, but this is NOT what I need to do (french accents should not be normalized).

So far, I find myself doing this:

```
if (str.includes(invalidAccents)){
    //do something
} else {
    //do something else
}
```

with a list I put together stored in an array:

```
var invalidAccents = [
    'á', 'ã', 'ä', 'å', 'ą', 'æ',
    'ĉ', 'ć',
    'ę',
    'ĝ',
    'ĥ',
    'í', 'ì', 'ł',
    'ĵ',
    'ñ', 'ń',
    'ó', 'ò', 'õ', 'ö', 'ø', 'œ', 'ó',
    'ŝ', 'ś',
    'ú', 'ŭ',
    'ÿ', 'ý',
    'ž', 'ź', 'ż',
    'ª',
    'ð',
    'ß',
    'ƒ',
    'þ',
    'µ',
    'Á', 'Ã', 'Ä', 'Å', 'Ą', 'Æ',
    'Ĉ', 'Ć',
    'Ę',
    'Ĝ',
    'Ĥ',
    'Í', 'Ì', 'Ł',
    'Ĵ',
    'Ñ', 'Ń',
    'Ó', 'Ò', 'Õ', 'Ö', 'Ø', 'Ó', 'Œ',
    'Ŝ', 'Ś',
    'Ú', 'Ŭ',
    'Ÿ', 'Ý',
    'Ž', 'Ź', 'Ż',
    'Ð',
    'Þ' 
];
```

but this is far from efficient and far from exhaustive.

Does anyone have an alternative solution or at least a place where I can find a complete list of accents to complete what I've got going?

Comment: It would be a lot simpler to check the string only contains allowed characters rather than check for illegal characters. There are only a limited number of accents allowed in English/French, but an enormous amount of characters in Unicode.

Comment: fair point. Still, thats over 70 characters in an array. Is there not a more efficient method?

Comment: Just use a regex `^[A-Za-z]+$`

Comment: @QuentinVeronthis would return false for french accents. This is not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the short answer is: aside using lists, you can use Unicode ranges, but this way requires to iterate strings and check each character separately..

See [`charCodeAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) and such.

If you look at [Unicode table](https://unicode-table.com/), you can see that codes 192-214, 217-221, 224-229 etc correspond to symbols with accents (I'd recommend to check it youself, I'm not sure whether 'ß' is called a symbol with accent).

Iterating to check those can look like:

```
function containsAccented(str) {
    const ranges = [[192,214], [217,221], ....];
    for(let c of str) {
        let code = c.charCodeAt(0);
        for(let range of ranges)
            if(code >= range[0] && code <= range[1])
                return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you want to automate somehow creating the ranges themselves, you have to find a proper definition of "not found in English or French" and whether some service describes those, not sure if there's any.

Comment: console.log(containsAccented('hello')); returns undefined <- should be false

Comment: console.log(containsAccented('héllo')); returns true <- should be false

Comment: console.log(containsAccented('héllö')); returns true <- should be true

Comment: @Sweepster, like I said, you have to adjust the ranges by yourself according to your needs. Presumably also invert the logic like JacquesB has suggested

Comment: I did set up the ranges as needed. Even if I invert the logic, it doesn't explain why I'm getting undefined.

Comment: @Sweepster ah, you want it to return `false`? That's simple, just add `return false;` in the end (see the edited version). But that doesn't actually matter if you use returned value for boolean checks

Answer (score 0):

You are probably best off approaching this somewhat differently: check if the string *only contains valid* characters, rather than checking if it *doesn't contain invalid* characters. Once you've figured what range would work best, you can use a [**regular expression**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to solve this kind of task. For example, let's say the acceptable characters are A-Z, irregardless of case; and whitespace is okay too. We would create this regular expression:

```
var validCharactersRegexp = /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/i;
```

That looks like a pretty big code, if you aren't familiar with regexps! Let's break it down:

- The whole thing is wrapped in slashes (`/`). This is the syntax that JavaScript uses for regular expressions. (We could do `= new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z\s]+$', 'i'`) and get the same result, but `/blah/` syntax is more concise and common.)
- `^` means that when we use this regexp, we'll be starting at the very beginning of the string.
- `[A-Z\s]` is a regular expression shorthand that means "any of these characters, but not any other character". `A-Z` are our letters; `\s` means any whitespace character.
- The `+$` part means we'll be searching for whatever's immediately before the `+`, until we reach `$` - that's similar to `^`, but it means the *end* of the string. Essentially, this means we'll be searching the entire string and making sure that every character in it matches the regular expression code before `+`.
- At the end, after the `/`, the `i` is a *flag* which means that the regular expression should be case-insensitive. (There are [several flags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags_2) available to us in JavaScript, but `i` is the only one that matters here.)

Now that we've got our actual regular expression, we have to use it to check if an input string is valid - that is, if it matches our regular expression. We'll use the [`.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) function to do that:

```
function isValid(string) {
    return validCharactersRegexp.test(string);
}
```

Just to show this works, here's a quick demo:

```js
var validCharactersRegexp = /^[A-Z\s]+$/i;

function isValid(string) {
    return validCharactersRegexp.test(string);
}

// Should be true.
console.log(isValid('apple'));

// Should also be true.
console.log(isValid('BaNaNa'));

// Should also be true!
console.log(isValid('Thou art a programmere'));

// Should be false - we didn't include punctuation in our regular expression after all.
console.log(isValid('Art thou a programmere?'));

// Should be false - "à" isn't in our regular expression.
console.log(isValid('Voilà'));
```

(PS: If you *really* wanted to use a blacklist, i.e. to search for invalid characters rather than valid ones, a regular expression would work for that too. Just do `[^...]`, where `...` are the characters that aren't allowed. The caret means the `[..]` will behave the opposite as normal - it'll match only if the current character is *not* one of the ones it specifies. Remember to adjust the regular expression accordingly - in this case, instead of searching for *all* characters being valid, we're searching for *any* character being invalid. So no need for `^[..]+$` - instead we'd just do `/[^...]/.test(string)`, to see if an invalid character appears anywhere in the string.)

Answer (score -1):

Create a list of the valids one, this list is kwown and short.

You can find inspiration with the iso-8859-15 charset:
https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/CEI_8859-15